# React native redux props not updated after calling an action

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react, react native, and redux, I have a react native app that has this login in render

```
    render() {
       return (<TouchableOpacity style={Style.btnSubmit} onPress={this.onLoginPressed.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={Style.btnText}>Login</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>)
}
```

and the onLoginPressed function is here

```
onLoginPressed() {
        const { username, password } = this.props.form;
        this.props.login({ username, password}); // the login is using the fetch api

        // props are not updated with the new state values
        console.log(this.props)
    }
```

Everything is working correctly but 
the props doesn't update in the onLoginPressed function, however, when I console log the props inside the render function, it's updated.
I understand that redux do a full rendering, but I  just don't really understand if it should update the props after calling the login.

Thank you

**Update** 
Here is the end of the component

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ...state.login
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        login: (formData) => dispatch(login(formData)),
        facebookLogin: (formData) => dispatch(facebookLogin(formData)),
        setUsername: (username) => dispatch(setUsername(username)),
        setPassword: (password) => dispatch(setPassword(password)),        
    }
}


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

here is the action

```
import { Host, Endpoints } from '../config/server';
import { loginActions } from '../config/constants';


/*
    * state props
        - form
        - inProgress
        - error
        - data
*/

export function login(form) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loggingIn(true));
        fetch(Host + Endpoints.auth.login, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(form)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => { 
                dispatch(loggingIn(false));                
                res.error ? dispatch(loginError(res.error)) : 
                            dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch(loginError(err)));
    }
}

export function facebookLogin(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loggingIn());

        fetch(Host + Endpoints.auth.facebookLogin, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => dispatch(loginSuccess(data)))
        .catch(err => dispatch(loginError(err)));
    }
}

export function setUsername(username) {
    return {
        type: loginActions.setUsername,
        username
    }
}

export function setPassword(password) {
    return {
        type: loginActions.setPassword,
        password
    }
}

function loginSuccess(data) {
    return {
        type: loginActions.LoginSuccess,
        data
    }
}

function loginError(error) {
    return {
        type: loginActions.LoginError,
        error
    }
}

function loggingIn(val) {
    return {
        type: loginActions.LoggingIn,
        inProgress: val
    }
}
```

and here is the reducer

```
import { loginActions } from '../config/constants';

const initialState = {
  form: {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  },
  data: null,
  inProgress: false,
  error: null
};

export default function loginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case loginActions.LoggingIn: 
            return {
                ...state,
                inProgress: action.inProgress
            }            
        case loginActions.LoginError:
             return {
                ...state, 
                error: action.error,
            }

        case loginActions.LoginSuccess:
            return {
                ...state,
                inProgress: false,
                error: null,
                data: action.data
            }
        case loginActions.setUsername:
            return {
                ...state,
                form: { 
                    username: action.username,
                    password: state.form.password
                }
            }
        case loginActions.setPassword:
            return {
                ...state,
                form: { 
                    username: state.form.username,
                    password: action.password
                }
            }
        default: 
            return {
                ...state
            }
    }
}
```

and the reducer index file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import login from './login';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and the configureStore file

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default function configureStore() {
  let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))
  return store
}
```

of course the root is wrapped with the provider passing the store.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong there.  I think you'll have to provide the whole component so people can see if you're connected correctly with Redux

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough, So it supposed to update the props? 
I updated my question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing console.log in the same function call that dispatch the login actions. That won’t work, because JavaScript is non-blocking, it will not wait for the login action to complete and update the props before calling console.log

Try console.log in something like componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: I understand that, thank you.

So do you suggest I should move my logic to componentWillReceiveProps? by logic I mean validating the response, toast errors, in case of success save data and move on, etc...

Comment: I think it is still better to make the component react to prop change instead of us trying check for prop change. E.g. there is a toast component that will show error when the prop changes. But I have definitely found myself doing some props change checking in componentWillReceiveProps to update things. A lot of things could be handled at redux-action level, like saving data in case of success. And if redux action starts to get out of hands and hard to maintain, I suggest taking a look at redux-saga or redux-observable to better separate concerns.

Comment: I'm trying to build a solid architecture because I know this project will be taken by other developers and will be maintained later in the future.
Thank you so much, that helped a lot.

Comment: I agree.  Try to avoid watching for changes and just have the component just display the correct thing for a given state.  However, that may not apply for firing off a call to display an error message (if it's a toast error message or some sort of pop up).  Your props may update multiple times for one render and you wouldn't want to display a new error pop up each time any given prop updates.  So that's one of the few places to watch for a change. If the error is inline (like next to an input) then you don't need to watch for a change