# React native redux able to read value but unable to update value in the same page

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I'm able to read the value of redux store(Props) but i'm unable to update the redux state value(Props2), when it seems like the action is dispatched to the reducer function.

[image]

Page:

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Props:"+this.props.user)
}

dummyFunction() {
    //Redux
    this.props.toggleTheme('red');

    //which prints the object above in the screenshot
    console.log(this.props.toggleTheme('red'));    

    console.log("Props2:"+this.props.user);
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user.userData,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  toggleTheme: (user) => dispatch(toggleTheme(user)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Tab1Screen);
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    userData: "Apple",
  };

  const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'TOGGLE_THEME':
        switch(action.payload) {
          case 'red':
            console.log("Payload1:"+ action.payload);
            return { userData: "Orange" };
          case 'blue':
          console.log("Payload2:"+ action.payload);
            return { userData: "Pear" };
        }
      default:
      console.log("Payload:3"+ action.payload);
        return state;
    }
  };

  export default user;
```

Actions:

```
import { TOGGLE_THEME } from './actionTypes';
//which TOGGLE_THEME = 'TOGGLE_THEME'

export const toggleTheme = user => ({
  type: TOGGLE_THEME,
  payload: user,
});
```

Package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
  }
```

Update: Tried to retrieve the state when I navigate to another page and it's working correctly, retrieving orange value. How would I be able to get the correct value in the same page(in dummyFunction)?

Comment: I would say instead of returning a new state obj in your reducer you can modify it like so `return {...state, userData: "Orange"}`  and for debugging purposes try to simplify your switch statement to see what is going wrong

Comment: Hi @AmrAly, i have tried ...state with no avail. The weird thing is that the updated value is retrieved once you navigate to another page, meaning that the switch statement is working fine.

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107402/react-native-redux-props-not-updated-after-calling-an-action) answer the guy says that you can't just console log in the same function instead you can do it in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: Even when I invoke the function the 2nd time , it still shows me "red". I'm guessing its more towards the "mapStateToProps" not refreshing.

Comment: try to console log your state in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: did that, cannot console inside mapStateToProps. Redux does not allow that sadly

Comment: you can console log like this:

`const mapStateToProps = state => (
console.log('state:',state);
return {
  user: state.user.userData,
});`

Comment: You can do that like so `const mapStateToProps = state => { console.log('state:',state); return { user: state.user.userData, }};`

Comment: @AmrAly tried to do so , and i'm able to get my value in mapStateToProps

Comment: So it changes userData value?

Comment: No, same page function still cannot get Orange. But the value is reflected in mapStateToProps.

Comment: As in the answer below the value change should be detected in life-cycle methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you can get the changed redux state immediately after setting it (dispatching an action).

What you can do is:

- Dispatch `toggleTheme` action in `dummyFunction`
- Detect the change in props using the lifecycle methods such as [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) or [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)
- On detecting change in `user` prop, use it as you wish

Comment: I think the problem that he is trying to catch the change in the same function `dummyFunction` but should be detected in a life-cycle method as per your answer.